# How to find the value of an array attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following script that outputs a json formatted object:

```
function test() {
    autoscaling.describeAutoScalingGroups(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // successful response
    });
}

test();
```

This outputs the following json:

```
{
  "ResponseMetadata": {
    "RequestId": "##################"
  },
  "AutoScalingGroups": [
    {
      "AutoScalingGroupName": "################",
      "AutoScalingGroupARN": "arn:aws:autoscaling:eu-west-1:#########:autoScalingGroup:###########",
      "LaunchConfigurationName": "######-LC-###########",
      "MinSize": 0,
      "MaxSize": 0,
      "DesiredCapacity": 0,
      "DefaultCooldown": 300,
      "AvailabilityZones": [
        "eu-west-1b",
        "eu-west-1c",
        "eu-west-1a"
      ],
      "LoadBalancerNames": [
        "#########-ELB-###########"
      ],
      "TargetGroupARNs": [

      ],
      "HealthCheckType": "ELB",
      "HealthCheckGracePeriod": 300,
      "Instances": [

      ],
      "CreatedTime": "2017-11-08T18:22:05.093Z",
      "SuspendedProcesses": [
        {
          "ProcessName": "Terminate",
          "SuspensionReason": "User suspended at 2017-11-08T18:22:14Z"
        }
      ],
      "VPCZoneIdentifier": "subnet-######,subnet-#######,subnet-#######",
      "EnabledMetrics": [

      ],
      "Tags": [
        {
          "ResourceId": "#######-ASG-##########",
          "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group",
          "Key": "aws:cloudformation:logical-id",
          "Value": "ASG",
          "PropagateAtLaunch": true
        },
        {
          "ResourceId": "#######-ASG-#########",
          "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group",
          "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-id",
          "Value": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:########:stack/##############",
          "PropagateAtLaunch": true
        },
        {
          "ResourceId": "################",
          "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group",
          "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-name",
          "Value": "#######",
          "PropagateAtLaunch": true
        }
      ],
      "TerminationPolicies": [
        "Default"
      ],
      "NewInstancesProtectedFromScaleIn": false
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to get the value of `"SuspendedProcesses":[{"ProcessName"`: (see above)

Then if the value of `"ProcessName" == "Terminate"` (as it is above) do this else do this.

I know how to construct the if else syntax but how do I establish the value of `"ProcessName"` from the JSON output beforehand?

I also know how to manipulate an array created in a script but I'm having difficulty here because the json object is being created by the `test()` function so the normal rules don't seem to apply.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, replace your console.log() calls with return statements. Then you can just do

```
var json = test();
var processes = json["AutoScalingGroups"][0]["Suspended Processes"]
```

updated code:

```
function test() { 
    autoscaling.describeAutoScalingGroups(params, function(err, data) { 
        if (err) {
            return [err, err.stack]; // an error occurred 
        } else {
            var json = JSON.stringify(data); // successful response 
            return json["AutoScalingGroups"][0]["Suspended Processes"];
        }
    }); 
} 
var processes = test()
console.log(processes);
```

Comment: `json` will be `undefined`

Comment: `First, replace your console.log() calls with return statements.` @Andreas its the first sentence

Comment: [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: thanks for your responses. I've updated my script with your suggestions (see below):

Comment: function test() {
      autoscaling.describeAutoScalingGroups(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) return(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else     return(JSON.stringify(data));           // successful response
    });   
    }

    var json = test();
    var processes = json["AutoScalingGroups"][0]["Suspended 
    Processes"]

    console.log(json);

Comment: @sharksdev `return()` isn't correct, return is not a function you just say `return ` I added your formatted code to my post and made that change

Comment: if you wouldn't mind, edit your original answer with your solution so that other people finding this with a similar problem can get help @sharksdev

Comment: @sharksdev can you accept my answer as correct? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks @RobbieMilejczak, problem resolved:

First, replace your console.log() calls with return statements. Then you can just do

```
var json = test();
var processes = json["AutoScalingGroups"][0]["Suspended Processes"]
updated code:

function test() { 
    autoscaling.describeAutoScalingGroups(params, function(err, data) { 
        if (err) {
            return [err, err.stack]; // an error occurred 
        } else {
            var json = JSON.stringify(data); // successful response 
            return json["AutoScalingGroups"][0]["Suspended Processes"];
        }
    }); 
} 
var processes = test()
console.log(processes);
```